# How to center text in menu excluding icon?

Tags: html, css, menu, icons, center

I have a menu with **centered text** in it, but i want to add icons to two of the menu bookmarks. I wanted them to be on the left, so i used `"float: left"` but now text is moved a little bit to the right because of the icon.

I'll just show this on pictures:

> **- It was like this:**

[image]

> **- Now it's like this:**

[image]

> **- And i want that:**

[image]

I cant come up with any clever idea to solve this problem in a simple way :/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="ofirmie.php" <?php if ($choosen == 0) {echo ' class="current" ';} ?> > <img src="structure/home.png" class="icon"> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="oferta.php" <?php if ($choosen == 1) {echo ' class="current" ';} ?> >Oferta</a></li>
    <li><a href="realizacje.php" <?php if ($choosen == 2) {echo ' class="current" ';} ?> >Nasze realizacje</a></li>
    <li><a href="kosze.php" <?php if ($choosen == 3) {echo ' class="current" ';} ?> >Kosze gabionowe</a></li>
    <li><a href="sport.php" <?php if ($choosen == 4) {echo ' class="current" ';} ?> >Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.php" <?php if ($choosen == 5) {echo ' class="current" ';} ?> >Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="ofirmie_en.php" <?php if ($choosen == 6) {echo ' class="current" ';} ?> >English version</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
/*  ---- MENU ---- */

#navi {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px #BFE0EB;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px #BFE0EB;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px #BFE0EB;
}

#navi ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 2em;
}

#navi li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5DBCD2;

}

#navi ul:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #5DBCD2;
}

#navi a {
    color: #696969;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#navi a:hover, #navi a.current {
    color: white;
    background-color: #319FE8;
}

img.icon{
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Use `background-image` for the `li` or `a` instead of inserting an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this would be to give the parent `li` a `position:relative;` and then you can give the image a `position:absolute;` along with `left` positioning.

See an example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jm9qgbcx/

Based on your provided code, your CSS would look like this:

```
#navi li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5DBCD2;
    position:relative;
}
img.icon {
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thx, it works ! I tried position: absolute before, but i forgot about changing parent element to position: relative.

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

**Try This**

```
img.icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
}
```

Comment: The main point is to center text, not icon. When there is an icon, text is moved 24px to the right and i dont want that

Comment: please check this new one

Comment: Frits was faster, and also i need this:  #navi li {position:relative;}
But thx for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
#navi li {        
    position:relative;
    padding-left:30px;
}
img.icon {
   position:absolute;
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   top:8px;
   left:5px
```

}

Comment: The main point is to center text, not icon. When there is an icon, text is moved 24px to the right and i dont want that.